# How do I Export Data to Excel using Spring, Hibernate, and PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a project which has one model class, Person with three Columns: id, name, and country, which correctly persists to PostgreSQL.  The results are correctly found in `List` objects. But I want to export the `List` data (which displays on the page) to Excel.

I made a class named `PersonExcelView`:

```
public class PersonExcelView extends AbstractExcelView {
    private PersonService personService;
    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> arg0, HSSFWorkbook arg1, HttpServletRequest arg2,
            HttpServletResponse arg3) throws Exception {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet("PersonList");
            setExcelHeader(excelSheet);

        List personList = (List) personService.getPersonList();
        setExcelRows(excelSheet,personList);

    }

    public void setExcelHeader(HSSFSheet excelSheet) {
        HSSFRow excelHeader = excelSheet.createRow(0);
        excelHeader.createCell(0).setCellValue("Id");
        excelHeader.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");
        excelHeader.createCell(2).setCellValue("Country");
    }

    public void setExcelRows(HSSFSheet excelSheet, List personList){
        int record = 1;
        for (Person person : personService.listPersons()) {
            HSSFRow excelRow = excelSheet.createRow(record++);
            excelRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(person.getId());
            excelRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(person.getName());
            excelRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(person.getCountry());

    }

}}
```

Here is my `PersonServiceImpl` class:

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        this.personDAO.addPerson(p);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updatePerson(Person p) {
        this.personDAO.updatePerson(p);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        return this.personDAO.listPersons();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        return this.personDAO.getPersonById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removePerson(int id) {
        this.personDAO.removePerson(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listPersons();
    }

}
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getExcel() {
        List personList = (List) personService.getPersonList();
        return new ModelAndView("PersonExcelView", "personList", personList);
    }
```

and here is the JSP:

```
<a href="SpringMVCHibernate/export">Export</a></h3>
```

When I click export, it does not export the data into Excel.  Where is the error?

Comment: You have to give more context as to "it does not export". What is showing up when you call that endpoint? Are you aware that your method is HTTP POST and not GET. With your `<a href=` it is making the call as a GET.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for exporting data to excel sheet and do changes as per your code requirement.

```
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();           
              XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("PersonList");         
              XSSFRow row;      
                     for (Object obj : objectArr)// for (Person person : personService.listPersons()) 
                     {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
                        cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                     }               
                for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 24; columnIndex++) {
                      spreadsheet.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
                    }

                      if(List.size()!=0)
                      {
                          FileOutputStream out;                      
                          out = new FileOutputStream(new File(file_path));                     
                          workbook.write(out);
                          out.close();
                      }
```