# export to excel but the content is garbled in spring mvc?

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to export to excel file(.xls) in spring mvc environment and the spring mvc version is 4.3.2.RELEASE,however the excel file`s content is not right
[image]
my code are as follows:

```
public class ViewExcel extends AbstractXlsView {

@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

List<BandedWordDo> bandedWordDos = (List<BandedWordDo>) model.get("list");
//创建工作薄
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("bannded word");
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER); // 创建一个居中格式
for (int i = 0; i < bandedWordDos.size(); i++) {
  Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
  // 第四步，创建单元格，并设置值
  String word = bandedWordDos.get(i).getWord();
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue(word);
}

//设置头信息
String agent = request.getHeader("USER-AGENT").toLowerCase();
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8");
final String fileName = "bandedWord";
String codedFileName = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
if (agent.contains("firefox")) {
  response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
  response.setHeader("content-disposition",
          "attachment;filename=" + new String(fileName.getBytes(),
                  Charset.forName("UTF-8")) + ".xls");
} else {
  response.setHeader("content-disposition",
          "attachment;filename=" + codedFileName + ".xls");
}
```

}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/word/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView exportBanded(ModelMap modelMap) throws IOException {
  List<BandedWordDo> bandedWordDos =  bandedService.getBandedWordList(Constants.NORMAL);
  modelMap.put("list", bandedWordDos);
  return new ModelAndView(new ViewExcel(), modelMap);
```

}

Comment: Remove the manipulating of the response from the view. That is already taken care of and you are basically interfering with that.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134161/how-do-i-export-data-to-excel-using-spring-hibernate-and-postgresql/39137280#39137280